# Auto Layout Setup

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've got the below layout and I've got it working well on iPhones, landscape only.

The PickerViews are currently populated with an image array. Currently, I force resize the images in the PickerViews based upon device size by setting the PickerView row height and image height to what fits each specific device (iPhone 5 -7+). However, to work on an ipad, I need to expand the ImageView in the center.

When I change the hugging values to >= it allows it to grow too large and pushes the PickerViews out the side on iPhones, despite them having a 4nit margin to superview. I've tried playing with the hugging/compression priorities but I can't make any headway.

Each item is in its own stack view. What is the best way to go about this?

[Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQrPo.png)

Comment: try to break your text in 2- 3 line. hard to read your essay

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the exact layout code you are using or a sample project if you are using interface builder (uploaded to github or something like that). It's very difficult to help you because we don't know the exact details of your layout hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add leading and trailing constraints to ImageView? As I understand you set the sizes to pickerViews?

Anyway, could you tell all constraints you have added? And how your elements should be resized on different devices(how can be compressed if there is not enough space)